# PouchDB Extension not showing second database

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

I’ve only just started using PouchDB (with Ionic), so I’m still working on wrapping my head around everything and getting it all set up (all my experience is in MySQL).

I have a simple Ionic app working with PouchDB and some basic CRUD abilities, now I’m trying to visualise what I’m doing using the PouchDB Extension for Chrome. So far so good, I click a “+” button to add an item to a list and the new database shows up under “Databases” in the PouchDB Extension.

Now I’m doing the exact same thing for a second database, and it’ll put my newly created items in a separate list, all seems to be good, I can edit and delete these items as well, just like in the first database. But this second database won’t show up in the PouchDB Extension and for the life of me I can’t figure out why, I’m doing exactly the same as with the first database.

This is part of my code for the first database:

```
function initDB() {
    _db = new PouchDB('threads');
};

function addThread(thread) {
    return $q.when(_db.post(thread));
};
```

And then this is what I'm doing for the second one:

```
function initDB() {
    _db = new PouchDB('categories');
};

function addCategory(category) {
    return $q.when(_db.post(category));
};
```

Btw: [This is the tutorial](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) I've followed to get the PouchDB part of my Ionic app working. (Basically just followed part of it twice to get the second database working)

**Edit:** So I just found the "application" tab in Chrome's developer tools (again, I come from MySQL databases, never worked with local storage before). I can view the Web SQL databases there and both my databases **do** show up there, but still only the first one is shown in the PouchDB extension :(

**Edit 2:** Alright this is turning into a whole different problem. I was aware that the PouchDB extension doesn't support the websql adapter, I thought PouchDB defaulted to IndexedDB but apparently idb isn't available in my Chrome installation? If I do the following to explicitly say I want to use the IndexedDB adapter:

`_db = new PouchDB('threads', {adapter: 'idb'});`

I get the following error: *Error: Invalid Adapter: idb*

If open the page in either Firefox or Chrome Canary I get no errors at all, and after adding the PouchDB inspector to Canary everything works as I want it to. I did update Chrome to the latest version (Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit)).

Any ideas as to why my regular Chrome installation doesn't support IndexedDB? (it should right, or am I going nuts? (I feel like I am))

**Edit 3:** Ok even though I feel like I'm talking to myself I'll continue posting my findings. Since the problems seemed to lie with my Google Chrome installation I reinstalled it, problem solved. If someone has some idea of what went wrong I'm all ears, until then I'm finally continuing on my project haha..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issues, chrome extention doesnt support websql, only index db.
https://github.com/angular-pouchdb/angular-pouchdb/issues/63

you can try this to get the DB sizing etc.

```
db.info().then(function (resp) {
    //resp will contain disk_size 
})
```